# How to use private enums in other classes

Tags: java, enums, private

this is my superclass where i created an private enum

```
public class Media {

private String Title;
private enum Genre { Comedy, Horror, Action, Romance, Documentary, Thriller, Drama}

Genre genre;


public Media ()
{

}
public Media(String t, Genre g){

   this.Title=t;
   genre=g;

}
```

now i wanna use this in an subclass

```
public class Movies extends Media{
private String regi;
private int playtime;

public Movies(){

}

public Movies(String t, Genre g, String r, int playt)
{
    setTitle(t);
    genre=g;
    this.regi=r;
    this.playtime=playt;
}
```

but it is not working because its telling me that the enum is private when i send in the genre for the method of creating an Movie object? is it not possible to have a private enum and not use it in other classes or subclasses?

Comment: What do you think `private` means?

Comment: Make it public then

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the enum `protected` instead of `private`

```
protected enum Genre { Comedy, Horror, Action, Romance, Documentary, Thriller, Drama}
```

`Private` means only accessible in the class its declared.

`Protected` is same as private but derived classes have access to.

`Public` means access to all

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with Java but in the case of define visibility.  You define a **private** member(attribute,  property,  method) if you want to limitate the scope to the current class.  In case of want to have access from a derivate class but keeping the scope to the class or  derivates you should define it as **protected**.  **I strongly recommend to read a little bit about that because it is fundamental to understand all those basic concepts.**